JPA Blaze criteria with entityview - selective output
I am using blaze persistence framework with entityviews.
Suppose I have enetity view like
@EntityView
interface User {
   String getName();
   String getMobile();
   List<Address> getAddresses()
}

And, based on search criteria, I would like to have all the data in the results or some part of data data - i.e. user without addresses if those are not to be displayed in the output.
Is there a way to achieve that in the code? I am interesed in blaze persistence mostly but standard jpa/hibernate is also an option.
